# Why is our faucet under power?

Tags: water

Sometimes, ~about once a week we get a "peck", a "pinch" from the water when we touch it. So there is something wrong. We live in a 10 story building.

I tried to measure what is happening: I got myself a multimeter. I put one of the wire from the multimeter to the water, the other wire in the phase of a connector (for just a second!). The multimeter told me 230V.. is this normal?

Question: How can I measure safely that there is any current somehow in the faucet? How can I detect what is causing the problem?

UPDATE: there is no grounding in the building (it was built at about ~1970..). Is it life-threatening? What does the water faucet have to do with the grounding in the connectors? Or there need to be a grounding for the water pipes?

UPDATE#2: There is no electrical boiler or heater in the building, as far as I know.

Comment: Have an electrician test your building's ground connections.

Comment: It used to be normal to connect electrical grounds to water pipes. Sounds like equipment is connected to the water pipe and the water pipe might have been repaired with plastic pipes somewhere before it enters the ground.. It needs checking.

Comment: If you have a bidet, don't use it.

Comment: You should not measure between the faucet and only one "phase" but between both and the ground connector too. Add the results to your post. Note: mesuring 230V between a grounded water supply and the phase is normal, since the neutral conductor may (in)directly connected to the ground (depending on where you live). Even if you measure between neutral and the faucet, there might be a 230V reading because of the current of the electrical wires taking a diversion via the water pipes, which may cause a voltage drop. Note: at work I often get zapped due to static dischage established by the carpet.

Comment: Are you certain there is no earth / grounding in your building. There are many schemes whereby earth is supplied to domestic installations, but earth connections have (in the UK at least) always been a common feature of mains supplies. Sometimes plumbing pipes were used to provide the ground, but this is now forbidden as many water pipes are plastic.

Comment: Reminds me of [Should I call plumber or electrician?](http://www.memepile.com/pics/4486-o.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you are measuring 230V between the water and the hot phase on an electrical outlet?  Is that correct?  That seems like exactly what one would expect in a normal situation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not such unusual situation, you have measured voltage between water (or could be also faucet) and live from socket, you got 230V which is normal. Probable cause is the electric boiler, the heater could be damaged and it is leaking current into water and this is what you feel. Water pipes has to be grounded, yes.

Comment: So could it be a life-threatening problem? I will call an electrician, but I don't know from where can we get ground :)

Comment: If your electrical supply doesn't have a ground, the normal alternative is to hammer an earth stake into the ground next to the building.

Answer (score 4):

In some countries I've heard that it is not illegal to take a ground from the water system. This would allow ground-fault current to travel through the water pipes. This could be happening, and it is not safe.

Alternatively, you could just be arcing off static electricity especially if it's cold and dry and you're wearing fuzzy slippers and synthetic thermal pajamas.

Answer (score 1):

best way to find out if you are actually receiving a shock from the  tap is replace one lead of your meter with a wire long enough to reach outside to the ground and drive a screwdriver into the earth. with the wire hooked to it then measure from the faucet to  the ground itself if you see more than 1.8 volts AC using this setup  call your power company and  an electrician you  may have an open service neutral which is a  life threatening  situation to everyone in the building and also a fire hazard.[something  to read and also i am a member of mike holts forum so  these issues are  not new to me](http://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/All-HTML/HTML/Multipoint-Utility-Neutral-Problem-House-Burns-to-Ground~20040506.php)

Comment: The electrician still didn't had time to came, so I will do this that you wrote on the weekend. Many thanks.

Comment: So I did what you wrote, I even pured water to the screwdriver to make sure it's contacted with the ground and the wire that was contacted to the screwdriver. I put one of the wire from the multimeter to the ground wire, the other to the pouring water. I turned the multimeter to AC, even with low sensitivity and it showed me zero. So there is no life-threatening situation? Then why do we get a "peck", or how can I call it, a "pinch" from the faucet? Many thanks!

Comment: And why exactly 1.8V?

Comment: are you still getting a shock from it or  has the issue abated? as for the 18 volt figure a bad neutral will cause an elevation of voltage under normal load that will be as high as 63 volts. most people begin to feel a "shock" at 24 volts and a current of 3 milliamps